# CSS box shadow partly transparent?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a box shadow on all four sides. however in the bottom corner of the div, I have positioned a background image (png) to make the corner look like its folded. Is there a way I can make the box shadow transparent for the bottom corner? or is there any other way around this?

[image]

Mant thanks, p

Comment: If your corner is square and positioned absolute with `bottom: 0, right: 0` what stops you from doing this:  `bottom: -3px, right: -3px` where 3px are just guess (it should be your shadow size).

Comment: oh , ok i think i follow you. Are you saying the image will cover the shadow?

Comment: Is the box-shadow the thin green(?) line around the blue box?

Comment: hi Max, the box shadow is around the white container / div. If you look at the bottom right  corner you can see its rounded, however, I don't want this because of the png image replicating a fold

Comment: What @Everettss says is a good advise, but only for your specific case where: you don't use a parent background image, 2: hopefully you don't care about code reusability.

Answer (score 4):

**Explanation**

You can set `position: absolute` and negative `bottom` and `left` properties to the **corner** and `position: relative` to the parent element (**box**) to archive this.

Suppose this is your **box** and inside it's the **corner**.

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="corner"></div>
</div>
```

Our **box** has `5px shadow size`

```
.box {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(40,128,1,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(40,128,1,1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(40,128,1,1);
}
```

So, our **corner** will have `bottom: -5px` and `right: -5px;`

```
.box > .corner {
  bottom: -5px;
  right: -5px;
}
```

Remember we need our **corner** with `position: absolute;`

```
.box > .corner {
  position: absolute;
}
```

And the parent with `position: relative`

```
.box {
  position: relative;
}
```

To archive this using `bottom` and `left` properties.

[image]

---

**Demo | Snippet**

```css
body {
  background: #EFECCA;
  padding: 20px;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(40,128,1,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(40,128,1,1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(40,128,1,1);
}

.box > .corner {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #EFECCA;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  right: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="corner"></div>
</div>
```

---

*PS, next time post some code.*

Answer (score 2):

Here's a demo of what you want to achieve with pure CSS using pseudo-elements.

```css
.corner {
  position: relative;
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
.corner:before,
.corner:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px; /* border-left + border-top width = width Ie. (20px + 20px = 40px)*/
  height: 40px; /*Same applies here just picture two triangles forming a square*/
  bottom: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  content: "";
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 /*You can reduce each border width here in both before and after pseudo-elements*/
.corner:before {
  border-top: solid 20px transparent;
  border-right: solid 20px #EEEEEE;
  border-left: solid 20px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 20px #EEEEEE;
}
.corner:after {
  border-bottom: solid 20px transparent;
  border-left: solid 20px #B5B5B5;
  border-right: solid 20px transparent;
  border-top: solid 20px #B5B5B5;
}
.border-radius {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.border-radius:after {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
  -o-border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="corner border-radius">
  <h2>Folded Corner Example</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, sunt, quidem suscipit...</p>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT:**

Change folded size example:

```
.corner:before,
.corner:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px; /* border-left + border-top width = width Ie. (20px + 20px = 40px)*/
  height: 20px; /*Same applies here just picture two triangles forming a square*/
  bottom: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  content: "";
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 /*You can reduce each border width here in both before and after pseudo-elements*/
.corner:before {
  border-top: solid 10px transparent;
  border-right: solid 10px #EEEEEE;
  border-left: solid 10px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 10px #EEEEEE;
}
.corner:after {
  border-bottom: solid 10px transparent;
  border-left: solid 10px #B5B5B5;
  border-right: solid 10px transparent;
  border-top: solid 10px #B5B5B5;
}
```

Comment: Ricardo thats amazing thanks, one question is it possible reduce the size of the fold?

Comment: Of course it is possible! Let me edit my answer to clarify where to change the size.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use an offset position and a background to hide the shadow:

```css
div {
  width:580px;
  margin:2em auto;
  box-shadow:0 0 3px;
  padding :1em;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:5px;
  background:lightgray;
}
div:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  border-radius:5px;
  /* offset equal to box-shadow size */
  bottom:-3px;
  right:-3px;
  /*whatever size */
  height:1.5em;
  width:1.5em;
  /*whatever colors*/
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right, gray ,#333 50%, white 50%) ;
  /*eventually */
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px  1px white
}
```

```html
<div>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. </div>
```